# How to stick searchbar and remove space between navigation bar and searchbar in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, xcode11

I want to stick searchbar to navigation bar

My Screen looks like this:
[image: Original Output]

I want to remove space between search bar and navigation bar like this :
[image: Desired Output]

Here is my code :

```
struct TimelineView : View {

@State private var searchQuery: String = ""
var timeline: [Timeline] = []

var body: some View {

    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            SearchBar(text: self.$searchQuery)
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                Spacer()
                    .frame(width: 30)
                Image("CameraIcon")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 50.0 , height: 50.0)
                Spacer()
                    .frame(width: 30)
                Text("Whats in your mind ?")
                Spacer()
                    .frame(height: 90.0)
            }
            List(timeline) { item in
                TimelineCell(timeline: item)
            }
        }
    }
}
}

struct TimelineCell : View {
let timeline: Timeline
var body: some View {
    return NavigationLink(destination: RegistrationView()) {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {

            Text(timeline.name)
            Text(timeline.like)
                .font(.subheadline)
                .color(.gray)
        }
    }
}
}

#if DEBUG
struct TimelineView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    TimelineView(timeline: testData)
}
}
#endif
```

In my code Searchbar is custom UI created by UIViewRepresentable.

Comment: please add screenshots & code of your problems rather than google drive link.

Comment: @KetanOdedra I added code and screenshots .. Please check it.